# Iterate through a JSONArray in a JSONObject

Tags: javascript, java, json, iteration

I have a `JSONObject` with a `JSONArray`, and a key. I want to `iterate` through the array and find all the carmodels with color `red` in each `JSONObject`.

This is what i have so far but it's giving me a `JSONException: JSONObject["color"] not found`

```
JSONArray arr = responseBody.getJSONArray("carModels");
String redServices = "";
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    if(arr.getJSONObject(i).get("color").equals("red"))
        redServices += arr.getJSONObject(i).toString() + ", ";      
}
```

This is an example of the jsonObject

```
 {
  "carModels": [
    {
        "toyota": {
            "color": "green"
        }
    },
    {
        "mazda": {
            "color": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "vw": {
            "color": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "ford": {
            "color": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "honda": {
            "color": "black"
        }
    },
    {
        "tesla": {
            "color": "white"
        }
    },

],
"average": "red"
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: The JSON has neither the `services` nor the `status` fields you are using in the code

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Just realized that, changed now. I tried generalizing the problem

Comment: You have no logic to deal with the keys which are the car names. You should probably restructure the json so a single item in the carModels list looks like: {'color':'red','manufacturer':'tesla'}, then arr.getJSONObject(i).get("color").equals("red") could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I don't like `JSONObject`, you need to account for JSON keys in model having a random value e.g. `mazda` or `vw`. You can use `names()` method to find this value:

```
JSONArray carModels = responseBody.getJSONArray("carModels");
for (int i = 0; i < carModels.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject model = carModels.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONArray keys = model.names();
  for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); j++) {
    Object key = keys.get(j);
    if (model.getJSONObject(key.toString()).get("color").equals("red")) {
      joiner.add(key.toString());
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(joiner);
```

will output:

```
mazda, vw, ford
```

It would be better to change the JSON structure to have predictable keys e.g.

```
{
  "carModels": [
  {
    "brand": "toyota",
    "color": "green"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: works like a charm! Is it possible to filter the result to only return the car models?

Comment: @StanY updated, the line with `joiner.add` was changed

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code which will work for the given json and you can modify it as per your actual json:

```
public String getRedServicesFromJSON(JSONObject object){
    JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("carModels");
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
    for(int i = 0;i < arr.length(); i++){
        if("red".equals(arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(arr.getJSONObject(i).names().getString(0)).get("color")))
            joiner.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).toString());      
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

Comment: The string joiner should use `", "`, but OP should probably change the JSON structure.

Comment: It would be great if I could, I'm getting the 'JSONObject' through an API Call so I don't have control over the json. Have to work with this format

Comment: @DavidConrad I am helping him for the logical part. This formatting thing could be done by him. Thanks

Comment: @StanY In that case you can skip the very first line of the function and can pass the JSONObject instead of String.

Comment: @StanY Edited as per your inputs. I hope it's help you.

Comment: Thank you @ShivangAgarwal, unfortunately I am still getting `JSONObject["status"] not found` on this line `if("red".equals(arr.getJSONObject(i).get("status")))` I changed the logic to match my jsonObject

Comment: @StanY Please use the updated code you are using the old code.

Comment: I see, getJSONObject expects a key as a parameter instead of an integer, no?

Comment: @StanY if("red".equals(arr.getJSONObject(i).get("status"))) should be replaced by "red".equals(arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(0).get("color")) and next line as well.

Comment: @StanY Sorry, I write that code in context of jackson. I have updated the code as per your requirement. I hope it will help you.